# How to exclude second main while linking test exe with gradle?

Tags: c++, gradle, linker, googletest

I'm trying to integrate unit tests in a native (C++) gradle project but I can't seem to find a working solution. The problem occurs while linking the test executable since there are two wmains available (one for the main application, one for the unit tests). Does anyone know how to exclude one of them during the linking step?

Here's a minimal example of my setup:

**Project structure**

```
build.gradle
src
    -> main
        -> cpp
            -> main.cpp
            -> registry.cpp
        -> headers
            -> registry.hpp
    -> test
        -> cpp
            -> main_test.cpp
            -> test_registry.cpp
libs
    -> googletest
        -> 1.7.0
            -> include
                -> ...
            -> lib
                -> libgtest.a
```

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'cpp'
apply plugin: 'google-test-test-suite'

model {
    platforms {
        x86 {
            architecture "x86"
        }
        x64 {
            architecture "x86_64"
        }
    }

    components {
        main(NativeExecutableSpec) {
            baseName "Registry"
            targetPlatform "x86"
            binaries.all {
                cppCompiler.args "-std=c++11", "-municode", "-mwindows"
                linker.args "-municode", "-mwindows"
            }
        }
    }

    testSuites {
        mainTest(GoogleTestTestSuiteSpec) {
            testing $.components.main

            sources {
                cpp.source.srcDir 'src/test/cpp'
            }
        }
    }

    repositories {
        libs(PrebuiltLibraries) {
            googleTest {
                headers.srcDir "libs/googletest/1.7.0/include"
                binaries.withType(StaticLibraryBinary) {
                    staticLibraryFile =
                        file("libs/googletest/1.7.0/lib/libgtest.a")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

model {
    binaries {
        withType(GoogleTestTestSuiteBinarySpec) {
            lib library: "googleTest", linkage: "static"

            cppCompiler.args "-std=c++11", "-municode"
            linker.args "-municode"
        }
    }
}
```

**Error message**

```
:compileMainExecutableMainCpp
:linkMainExecutable
:mainExecutable
:assemble
:compileMainTestGoogleTestExeMainCpp
:compileMainTestGoogleTestExeMainTestCpp
:linkMainTestGoogleTestExe
C:\Users\minimal\build\objs\mainTest\mainCpp\e7f4uxujatdodel7e7qw5uhsp\main.obj:main.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `wmain'
C:\Users\minimal\build\objs\mainTest\mainTestCpp\271ezc0ay5ubap2l962cnectq\main_test.obj:main_test.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined here
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

:linkMainTestGoogleTestExe FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':linkMainTestGoogleTestExe'.
> A build operation failed.
      Linker failed while linking mainTest.exe.
```

**options.txt**

```
-o
C:\\Users\\minimal\\build\\exe\\mainTest\\mainTest.exe
C:\\Users\\minimal\\build\\objs\\mainTest\\mainTestCpp\\271ezc0ay5ubap2l962cnectq\\main_test.obj
C:\\Users\\minimal\\build\\objs\\mainTest\\mainTestCpp\\dp6ieaohq04qqqa31sdfwrsxj\\test_registry.obj
C:\\Users\\minimal\\build\\objs\\mainTest\\mainCpp\\68sxcjmhakj69ha7wqtijofs3\\Registry.obj
C:\\Users\\minimal\\build\\objs\\mainTest\\mainCpp\\e7f4uxujatdodel7e7qw5uhsp\\main.obj
C:\\Users\\minimal\\libs\\googletest\`.7.0\\lib\\libgtest.a
-municode
-m32
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem arises from trying to do the wrong thing with googletest.

Googletest is a *unit-testing* framework. That means it is for testing
*libraries* - where *library* here means *a bunch of functions and/or classes
that don't include a* `main` *function*. It is not for testing applications,
that have a `main` function. You test an application by running the
application and making controlled - possibly automated - observations
of its overt behaviour. That kind of testing has various names but is
not *unit-testing*, and unit-testing comes first.

To test a library with googletest, you need to create an application to
run your googletest test cases. That application, the test-runner, needs
its own `main` function, that does nothing but run the test cases:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

It's common enough for someone to have an application that contains
a bunch of application specific functions and/or classes that they'd
like to unit-test with googletest. The way to do that is:-

- Refactor the application into:

  - A library - call it the *app library* - that contains the functions and/or classes you want to
    unit-test, excluding the `main` function.
  - The remainder, including the `main` function.
- Build the application by linking the remainder with the app library.
- Create a test-runner application, comprising your googletest test cases
  and a googletest `main` function. Naturally, the test cases, `#include`
  the headers of the app library.
- Build the test-runner by linking the test cases and main function with the app library.
- Unit-test the app library by running the test-runner.

The simplest and quickest approach to this is just to put all of the application,
except for the `main` function, into the app library. But it's probably wiser
to move stuff from the application into the app library only *as you develop
unit tests to cover it*, so you know at any time that whatever is in the app library
has unit tests and the rest doesn't. Proceed in this way till everything except
the `main` function is in the app library, and has unit tests.

You will almost certainly find that the process of factoring out the app-library
so that you can link it with both the application and the test runner *exposes
design flaws in the application and forces you to do better*. This can start an
app library on its way to maturing into a multi-app library, a stable high-quality
software asset.

So you started with one project, the application project, and you end up with
three projects:

- A project that builds the app library
- A project that builds the application
- A project that builds the test runner

One way or another, any build system you have will allow you to make automatic
dependencies between these projects. Clearly, you want:

- Building the application to require building the app library
- Building the test-runner to require building the app libary

But you could go further, and make building the application require
building the test-runner - which will build the app library - *and successfully
running the test runner*. That way, you won't ever build the application
unless the unit tests are successful. That's probably overkill for your
desktop dev cycle but, but not for CI builds.

For the next application, you can *start* with this 3-project pattern,
and add functionality to the application only when you can get it from the
app library, which must be covered by unit tests, which must pass
in the test-runner. Then you're using googletest the right way.

Comment: Thank you for the extensive answer. I'm familiar with unit testing in general (not in the C/C++ context though) and already had the test cases set up correctly code-wise. I was however unaware of the implicit restrictions imposed on the project structure. As it's a really small application I opted for the quick/simple approach you described (root project contains only the main and a library project contains the "API" and its corresponding unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

In VS there is an explicit option on which main to use.
[image]